# When does a researcher become a computer scientist?

Tags: phd, research-process, postdocs, masters, science

When do you call a researcher a computer scientist? Are Master degree holders computer scientists? Are Phd degree holders computer scientists? Is there a certain level of experience after which the researcher will be called a computer scientist?

Comment: I reaaaally doubt that you will get a constructive, objective and useful answer to this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> When do you call a researcher a computer scientist?

A runner is someone who runs; a writer is someone who writes; a researcher is someone who does research; a computer scientist is someone who does computer science.  So if you're doing computer science research, **I** will call you a computer scientist and a researcher, even if you aren't yet published, even if you work full-time as a plumber, even if you're still in junior high school.

> Is there a certain level of experience after which the researcher will be called a computer scientist?

No.  There is nothing you can do to make other people call you anything.

But to call *yourself* a computer scientist, the only requirement is that you are doing computer science.  So in that sense, yes, there is a certain required level of experience: **More than zero.**